# How to prove that a set of functions is equivalent to the other set of functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, contest-math, functional-equations

I am trying to find a non-constructive proof for a simple example problem:

> Let set $B=\{g||\forall x, g(x)>0,g'(x)>0\}$;
>
> $A=\{f||f=v\cdot h, \text{and }  v,h\in B\}$. Prove that $A=B$.

I can first prove that $f'=v'h+vh'>0$,

So any $f\in B$;

Therefore $A\subseteq B$.

But is it possible to find a general way (i.e. not by construction) to prove that $B\subseteq A$?

My try: suppose that $g=h\cdot (g/h)$. We want to show that there exists $h$ such that $h'>0$ and $(g/h)'>0$.

$(g/h)'=(g'h-gh')/h^2$

It is greater than zero if and only if $g'h-gh'>0$;

That is, $h'<\frac{g'h}{g}$.

---

Where I can find a book/paper on the methods of proving these things? I guess for differentiable functions, we can prove that both sets are the solution set of the same differential equation?

Comment: Take $f\in B$ and let $g:=\sqrt{f}$. Try to show that $g\in B$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Yes this is the constructive proof. The specific construction might work for this specific case, but not in another problem.

Comment: You need to narrow the scope considerably from "proving any two descriptions of sets of functions describe the same set" if you want to get a useful answer. I'm pretty sure I could rephrase a question that is independent of ZFC in that format, for instance. And many number theory problems, etc.

Comment: @MarkS. Basically I am looking for a method to solve the example question without using constructive proof. sorry for being unclear